# Baire space $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$ written as $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: set-theory, real-numbers, descriptive-set-theory, the-baire-space

I'm writing my bachelor thesis on various topics from set theory and descriptive set theory (mainly topological games), and I just read a paper in which the Baire Space $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$ is dubbed $\mathbb{R}$. Here is how it justifies it:

> Since any two uncountable polish spaces are borel ishomorphic and since many set-theoretic questions are invariant under borel isomorphism it is customary to dub any uncountable polish space $\mathbb{R}$. Also in set theory it is often desirable to deal with a version of $\mathbb{R}$ which is transparent from a combinatorial point of view, so we will work with the Baire space $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$.

I don't really understand what they mean by "transparent from a combinatorial point of view". I have an intuition on why it is desirable to work with the Baire space. In fact I'd say that it is because it is pretty close to $\mathbb{R}$ (it is homeomorphic to the irrational numbers with the relative topology) and, in a certain sense, it allows to contruct its elements in a much simpler way than in $\mathbb{R}$. This emerges for example in the elegant characterization of continuous functions in the Baire space. So my questions are:

1. What do they mean by "transparent from a combinatorial point of view"?
2. Is my intuition on the construction of the baire space elements formalizable in some way? It is in some way related with the total disconnection of the space?
3. If the answer to the previous question is affermative then the reason why the Baire space is desirable can rely also on this consideration (on the element construction)?

Thanks!

EDIT: this is the link to the article I was quoting: [article](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/266993670_The_SLO_principle_and_the_Wadge_hierarchy)
I want to point out that the article doesn't say anything more than the quote I posted in this regard.

Comment: It can also be helpful if you tell us which paper that was.

Comment: You are right, I just added the link to the article.

Comment: I think [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/26395/212120) and the following comments are extremely relevant... If that answers your question, you can flag it as its duplicate.